# Is it reasonable to use percentages with UIScreen Height?

Tags: swift, swiftui, layout, uiscreen

Is it reasonable to use percentages with UIScreen Height to make auto layout in SwiftUi? I am quite new to Swift and I need to make an auto layout but as I know SwiftUI doesn’t have margins as UIKit. So I usually use height and width with percentages to make layout flexible for all iPhones. But I think that it is a bad option and hope that better ones exist.

Comment: UIScreen for measurements is deprecated so no it isn’t reasonable to use “old hacks” SwiftUI.Layout and GeometryReader should be all you need

Comment: You should never use `UIScreen` for relative layout as iPad split screen mode means the screen size won't equal window size. Moreover, if you use `UIScreen` for any measurements, that means your view won't be reusable as a non-full screen view even inside your app. You should always size your views relative to their containers, not the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your views size adapt to their container, you can use `GeometryReader` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Rectangle()
                .overlay { 
                    Text("Rectangle with height equal to 35% of its container")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                }
            .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 0.35)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: result of provided code example]